# Core Data Predicate one-to-many and many-to-one problem

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nspredicate

I have **Client** entities and **Job** entities.

Each job can have one client. The relationship for the jobs of a client (client<-->>job) is called jobOfClient.

Each client can have many jobs. The relationship for client of a job (job<<-->client) is called clientOfJob.

(Of course, these are inverse relationships.)

I have some predicates that are working, but the last one does not. Leaving out some of the fetchedResultsController set up, here are some of the key lines of code for three cases:

Here, I sort through jobs, looking for jobs that aren't related to any client:

```
NSEntityDescription * entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Job" inManagedObjectContext:dataInterface.managedObjectContext];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"clientOfJob == nil"];
```

Here I sort through jobs, looking for jobs of a particular client:

```
NSEntityDescription * entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Job" inManagedObjectContext:dataInterface.managedObjectContext];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"clientOfJob == %@", userState.selectedClient];
```

But this next one doesn't work. Here I sort through clients, looking for the one client associated with a selected job (or return no result if there is no related client, but that's not the case here).

```
NSEntityDescription * entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Client" inManagedObjectContext:dataInterface.managedObjectContext];    
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"jobOfClient == %@", userState.selectedJob];
```

The error message is **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'**

There must be something subtle here that I don't understand. Can someone help me with **the info I have given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jobOfClient` will return a collection of objects, which means your predicate is essentially doing:

```
NSSet *jobs = [thisObject jobOfClient];
return ([jobs isEqual:aJob]);
```

Obviously, a collection is never equal to a single value, and so CoreData does not recognize the predicate.  To get around this, I think you can do:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"jobOfClient CONTAINS %@", [userState selectedJob]];
```

And to make sure you don't run into this again, I would recommend changing the name of this relationship from `jobOfClient` to just `jobs` (using the plural form to indicate it's a to-many relationship, and eliminating the `OfClient`, because it's already on the `Client` entity).  Your other relationships should probably be similarly renamed.  `clientOfJob` => `client`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve the problem using this: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"ANY jobOfClient == %@", userState.selectedJob];  -- The keyword any caused it to look over all in the set.